# Laravel groupby Week Eloquent query

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

As a newbie to Laravel , I had some some doubts regarding the date formatter and  the blade templates.

I have written a query which is excuted in the correct way,
Following is my Eloquent SQL Query.

```
public function orderbyweek()
    {

        $orderbyweek = DB::table('sales_flat_order_items as s')
                ->leftJoin('sales_flat_orders as w', 'w.entity_id','=','s.order_id')
                ->select(array(DB::Raw('sum(s.amount_refunded) as amount_refunded'),
                    DB::Raw('sum(s.row_total) as row_total'),
                    DB::Raw('sum(s.discount_amount) as discount_amount'),
                    DB::Raw('sum(s.tax_amount) as tax_amount'), 
                    DB::Raw('sum(s.qty_ordered) as qty_ordered'),
                    DB::Raw('sum(w.subtotal) as subtotal'),
                    DB::Raw('WEEK(w.created_at) week'), 
                    DB::Raw('sum(w.total_invoiced) as total_invoiced'),
                    DB::Raw('sum(w.shipping_amount) as shipping_amount')
                    ))
                ->where('qty_canceled','=','0')
                ->where('status','!=','canceled')
                ->groupBy('week')
                ->orderBy('w.created_at')
                ->get();

            return View::make('sales_flat_orders.orderbyweek', compact('orderbyweek'));


    }
```

This show me the table where i want the week as in interval of 7 days. 
So in my template what will i need to do? How to add the date formatter for that? I have done something here:

```
<table width="100%">
    <thead>

        <th>DATE</th>
        </thead>

  @foreach($orderbyweek as $s)

  <tr>
     <td>{{date("d F, Y",strtotime($s->week))}}</td>

  </tr>

 @endforeach
</table>
```

I have the sql query executed which is the following:

```
select sum(s.amount_refunded) as amount_refunded, sum(s.row_total) as row_total, sum(s.discount_amount) as discount_amount, sum(s.tax_amount) as tax_amount, sum(s.qty_ordered) as qty_ordered, sum(w.subtotal) as subtotal, WEEK(w.created_at) week, sum(w.total_invoiced) as total_invoiced, sum(w.shipping_amount) as shipping_amount from `sales_flat_order_items` as `s` left join `sales_flat_orders` as `w` on `w`.`entity_id` = `s`.`order_id` where `qty_canceled` = '0' and `status` != 'canceled' group by `week` order by `s`.`created_at` asc
```

Where am i going wrong?

I am getting ordebydate, orderbyyear too. But Not Order by Week

[image: U can see the image of the table, Here see the week, Its not the porper one]

Please Help me out.

Answer (score 1):

This is used for month group-by by me, I think this will also work for week.

```
    $data = \Invoice::select(   
                        DB::raw("MONTHNAME(STR_TO_DATE(MONTH(date), '%m')) as month"),
                        DB::raw('SUM(g_total) as total_invoice_amnt'),
                        DB::raw('MONTH(date) as no_mnth')
                    );
                    foreach ($filters as $filter) {
                        if ($filter[2] != '') {
                            $data->where($filter[0], $filter[1], $filter[2]);
                        }
                    }
    $data = $data->groupBy("month")
                 ->OrderBy('no_mnth','ASC')
                 ->get()
                 ->toArray();

    return $data;
```

Comment: this is actually done..but not getting how to do for a interval of 7 days, ie. for week.

Comment: in your query you miss some thing like this DB::Raw('WEEK(w.created_at) week'), => DB::Raw('WEEK(w.created_at) as week'),

Comment: y this double arrow(=>) is der, U will surely get syntax error and it will not work out there.

Comment: DB::Raw('WEEK(w.created_at) week'), line replace with DB::Raw('WEEK(w.created_at) as week'), this i indicate you dude

Comment: yes, got that, and also i think the formatter used in blade template is wrong?? how to format it? for example: 7th,July-14th,july...may be from 7th,jul,sun-14th, july,sat. And in the interval of 7,

Comment: ie. from date- to date

Comment: in your blade you try to convert your week to date format but it can't possible you have to format your created_at field rather than week

Comment: I think i need to concat the (date) and the( week name) in my raw query something like this: CONCAT(DATE(w.created_at),' - ', DAY(w.created_at),'-',MONTHNAME(w.created_at)) AS 'Week'.

Comment: can you send me actually what you want in your blade view??

Comment: DB::Raw('CONCAT(DAY(w.created_at),'-',DATE(w.created_at),'-',MONTHNAME(w.created_at)) AS week') can we do something like this

Comment: And wat about in template ??

Comment: But this syntax also doesnt work and i dont know why